# Convert List of String to a single Object

Tags: java, list, java-8

We have a list of String and would want to create an object using all elements in that list. List can have varying number of elements and  hence creating an object might cause NPE. What can be a better way to create an object ?

```
List<String> example = {'BookName', 'value','3'}

BookRating.build.getBookName(example.get(0)).getBookValue(example.get(1)).getRating(example.get(2)).build();
```

This might cause NPE when example has only 2 values. Any suggestions?

Edited: We can have objects with either 1/2/3 values.

Comment: You can check the length of the list and not build the rating if there are fewer than 3 elements

Comment: These objects can be created with just the first parameter

Comment: You can check the length in an if statement: `if (example.size() === 1) {...} else if (example.size() === 2) { ....}.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection like this:
group all *Book* class constructors by its size.

```
List<String> example = List.of("BookName", "value","3");

Map<Integer, Constructor<?>> groupBySize = 
       Arrays.stream(Book.class.getConstructors())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Constructor::getParameterCount, Function.identity()));
```

then invoke the constructor by *list* size and pass list values as arguments.

```
Book book = (Book) groupBySize.get(example.size()).newInstance(example.toArray());
```